# how to say it in grammatically correct way

Tags: grammaticality

You should enjoy a day from its start or beginning? which one is better to use? 
it is a grammatically correct way how to say it? 
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct and you can use whichever one you like more.

Comment: ...and perhaps you mean _each_ day.